# PyCharm cannot import BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to make a spider using bs4 on Python, I've already installed the bs4 using either pip and easy_install, but once I run the program using PyCharm, it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PyCharm Project/bs4.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "C:\PyCharm Project\bs4.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

But in the cmd prompt this error doesn't appear:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:16:59) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> html_doc = """
... <html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
... <body>
... <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
...
... <p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
... <a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
... <a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
... <a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
... and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
...
... <p class="story">...</p>
... """
>>>
>>> # create a bs object using a HTML page
... soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser', from_encoding='utf-8')
>>> soup.title
<title>The Dormouse's story</title>
>>> soup.title.string
"The Dormouse's story"
>>>
```

Project interpreter: 
[image]

Comment: what interpreter is being used in PyCharm?

Comment: @tales_padua 3.5.0 of python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You called your script `C:/PyCharm Project/bs4.py"`, with `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` you are  actually trying to import `BeautifulSoup` from your  own script not the `bs4` lib so you need to rename it and remove any `.pyc` file in the directory.

Comment: Yes that's the problem!! I renamed the python file into 'test.py' and now it works! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

chances are pycharm is configured to use python2.7 ... you can change to 3.5 under file > settings > project settings > interpretter

or

type `import bs4` at the top of your file ... when it is underlined with red, move the cursor under it ... and hit alt + enter, then select "install package bs4"

Comment: The interpreter is python 3.5 as the image I posted; I have already installed the bs4 so PyCharm doesn't underline the `import bs4` with red, in fact when I do `print bs4` it print the bs4 lib path.

Answer (score 0):

you should install it again  or you should change the  interpreter to python 3.5 or type import bs4 at the top of your file

Comment: I've already installed it for several times, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I used both "import bs4.BeautifulSoup" and "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup", it gives the same error. The interpreter is python 3.5.0.